# Navigation in multi-module/layer Android architecture

Tags: android, architecture

I decided to try multi-module Android app architecture and I've been experimenting with for a while.

For navigating between features, it is recommended to use **Deep Linking** in several articles.

I was wondering if anyone else has a different approach without using **Deep Linking** that won't cause dependency cycle.

This is the structure of my app. `base` module has shared pieces and all modules depend on `base` module. And `app` module is the top-level module that connects all my features.
[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a router in the App module and an interface that it implements in the base module. Each feature module will reference the interface since they already have the dependency on the base module. App module will create the router and inject it into the feature modules.

Comment: This is the setup I had, in this, we have to pre-define the screens we will transition to and place inside implementation I believe? Features don't know about each other.